# Left to right alignment in multicol

Tags: multicol

I'm writing an Hebrew lyx document, when I use multicol to use multiple columns it does makes the columns left to right, how can I change it to right to left?

thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a fully compilable example? It would help solvers a lot! My tip: please try `bidi` package.

Comment: The `multicol` package has a `\RLmulticolcolumns` (alignment) command, which must by applied before `\begin{multicols}`; I can't test because I have no knowledge on Right to left languages at all, but have a look on page 4 of the documentation please, to be found here http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments.